# Has somebody successful connected Compose provided PostgreSQL to Eclipse's database viewer?

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.4, compose-db

I'm trying to do it, but getting `Connection failed with unspecified error`, the full stack trace you can see at the end of the topic. When I using **pgAdmin III** it work flawlessly, connection from the code using this driver `9.4-1206-jdbc41` no problem, only Eclipse doesn't work.

I've tried a bunch of drivers 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, nothing helped me.

I'm using the following format here:

[image]

```
Database: compose
URL: postgres://<username>:<password>@aws.......dblayer.com:10336/compose
Username: <username>
Password: <password>
```

**Eclipse version**: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

**The full stack trace of the exception**:

```
java.lang.Exception: Connection failed with unspecified error.
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:110)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.<init>(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my url was formatted in a wrong way, the correct format is following:

```
jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<database>
```

Credit goes to this thread: [Connect to Postgresql 9.2 from Eclipse Data Tools Platform](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30852/connect-to-postgresql-9-2-from-eclipse-data-tools-platform)